OpenAI Fine-tuning API error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'FineTune'"
I'm having an issue with the OpenAI Fine-tuning API, getting the same error message after having tried several versions:
ImportError: cannot import name 'FineTune' from 'openai.cli'
Which is related to the following imports:
from openai import FineTune as FineTune
from openai.cli import FineTune as FineTuneCli

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

The following is how you do fine-tuning with the OpenAI API:
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(
  training_file="file-abc123",
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo"
)

